# How can we be sure if Universe has exploded with big bang? Can't it be implosion?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

Why do we say the universe has exploded in the event of big bang? When we talk about big bang there was no concept of outside with the absence of space, so should’t the universe be imploded into the big bang from the single point? Also how can we say there was point as presence of point itself means space was already present, does this imply space was already there when big bang happened?

Comment: First, you are pretty much arguing semantics here. Second, saying it exploded (or any other similar word) is not really precise. I'm sure someone else here can give you a better understanding of cosmic inflation though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: BB wasn't an explosion, but it wasn't an implosion either. Also, current BB theory doesn't really describe the state of the universe at the exact t=0 instant, since we need a quantum gravity theory to deal with the very earliest phase of the BB.

Comment: I've suggested a duplicate because your question boils down to misconceptions about the nature of the Big Bang.  Forget "explosion" and think "expansion" is the way to go.  The key to grasping the Big Bang is the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe) and the big thing to remember is *we don't have a full understanding of the Big Bang* - (yet).

Comment: Big bangs and explosions seem to go together!